# jQuery mobile fails in the Opera Mini browser. How to get error output?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery-mobile, opera-mini

[image: viewed on Opera] I have a [jQuery Mobile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_Mobile) website that works great on normal browsers, but it fails when using Opera Mini or [Opera Mobile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_Mobile). I cannot get any error message. All I see is the jQuery mobile loading when viewed using Opera.

The application seems to work on other browsers. Here is a link to the site so as you view through Opera Mini: [demo](http://www.veepiz.com/touch/).

What is the output, so I know what Opera Mini is failing on? I googled to no avail.

Comment: i have a feeling app may fail cause of localstorage not working in opera, but ive tried jstorage polyfill but still fails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be because Opera Mini has a limited amount of JavaScript support?

Your best bet would be to rewrite what you need for Opera from the current support documentation guidelines from *[Opera Mini: web content authoring guidelines, JavaScript support](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-mini-web-content-authoring-guidelines/#javascript)*.

Comment: The furthest i got with this dilema, was opera mini was misbehaving with dynamically inserted data with $.mobile.changePage(); i was dynamically inserting pages within "pagebeforechange" event. ive decided to redo the site with no hash listening, ajax etc

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Opera Mobile Emulator](http://www.opera.com/sv/developer/mobile-emulator) together with an [older version of Opera](http://www.filehippo.com/download_opera/11494/) that has the Dragonfly inspector (replaced in newer versions with Webkit Inspector) and remote debug your website.

1. Load your page in Opera (desktop)
2. Right click anywhere and Inspect element
3. Click "Remote debug" (top right buttons)
4. Visit "opera:debug" in mobile emulator and connect

Comment: Latest version of Opera with Dragonfly seems to be http://www.opera.com/download/guide/?ver=12.17