# Website In Opera Mini Not Working Correctly But Working in All Other Browsers

Tags: browser, opera-mini

My website cinemaza.co.in is working correctly in all the browser in pc's & mobiles except Opera Mini. The main problem is with `display:inline-block` property. Please help me because most of my visitors are from opera mini.

Answer (score 1):

Check the current version of the browser. CSS inline-block is only supported for the current version of Opera Mini 5.0-7.0

More details can be visualized on [this site.](http://caniuse.com/inline-block)

Comment: my opera mini version is 7.5.33361 android

Comment: @user3439168 try debugging against emulator as described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18231783/2626313