# Referencing Jquery functions in <head> tags of opera mini 8

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would be really thankful if anybody could advise on jquery's weird behavior in opera mini 8 (full version is 8.0.1807.91281). When the following code is placed directly in head tags it works,

```
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"> type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#hasphone').show();
            $('#hasmail').show();
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

However, trying to keep my head nice and clean and doing the following simply stops this simple function's execution. I created my show.js file, placed it in my head and also referenced jquery like this:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="show.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"> </script>
</head>
```

Then I placed my simple function inside my show.js file like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hasphone').show();
    $('#hasmail').show();
});
```

It works fine in all the major browsers I tested it in (Opera Classic, IE, Safari, Chrome, FF) but it just fails in opera mini 8. Could anybody advise please, what I am doing wrong here? My vague guess is that opera mini 8 has its rendering stuff off this browser and does it remotely via their servers, that's why the only way for it to work in opera mini is to put the code directly in head. I am not sure I am on the right track here but that's the only workaround I've found so far **to force** it work in opera mini 8.

Would appreciate any help /comments at all as this thing slowly starts driving me crazy :-) Many thanks in advance!

-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-

P.S. Update.

I upgraded to jquery 1.11.3 and keep the lines in this order now:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="show.js"> </script>
</head>
```

But having it this way together with the following in my show.js still does not work in opera mini 8.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hasphone').show();
    $('#hasmail').show();
});
```

As soon as I change it to:

```
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#hasphone').show();
            $('#hasmail').show();
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

and disable my show.js it starts working everywhere including opera mini 8. I am totally clueless... Any more suggestions, please anyone?

-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-

Update 2. Solved.

The trick was in my other scripts' order. That is I reversed the order I had and it started to work. For example I had script1, script2, and script3 placed like this:

```
<script src="script1.js"> type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="script2.js"> type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="script3.js"> type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now I have changed it to:

```
<script src="script1.js"> type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="script3.js"> type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="script2.js"> type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and it all revived.

Hope it will help someone out there as well. Make sure you check your scripts' places and chances are it will work for your as well. Just remember it all has to go coherently and successively in accordance with your scripts' code.

Comment: You need to include `show.js` ***after*** `jquery.js`. I can only assume it works in any browser is due to some caching of the original script. Also note that jQuery 1.4.2 is very outdated (over 5 years old in fact), and should be updated.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying so quickly! I have tried reversing before but it won't help much. In fact, it's been "in reverse" position for quite some time now.

Comment: Try reading through : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12863268/jquery-mobile-fails-in-the-opera-mini-browser-how-to-get-error-output

Comment: I guess you hit the nail right on its head Rory about the jquery being a way too old. Thank you! As soon as I changed / upgraded it looks like it started working. Let's wait and see now how long it will last if that is not some kind of caching after effects as per your other suggestion.

Comment: Opera's Mini limited JavaScript support is not quite the case here, Starx but thank you for pointing out the link. Appreciate. Opera Mobile Emulators look cool but there aren't any opera minis as far as I understood it are there?

Answer (score 0):

You should include the `jQuery` first and then all its dependents.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="show.js"> </script>
</head>
```

Reverse the order in which they are loaded.

**EDIT**

```
<script src="jquery.js"> type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--                   ^         -->
```

Remove the closing bracket of `script`.

Comment: Appreciate your help Tushar. jQuery has been sitting first for quite a long time now. I experimented with reverse orders earlier but the results are still the same...

Comment: Hey! Good point Tushar. Thank you once again. Don't you just hate these darn little typos. Well, it worked OK though with that bracket as well.